# How can I box the contents of an iterator of a type that implements a trait?

Tags: iterator, rust, boxing

I'm taking an iterator of some type that must implement the trait `A`, and trying to convert it into a `Vec` of `Box`es of that trait:

```
trait A {}

fn test2<'a, I>(iterator: I) -> Vec<Box<A + 'a>>
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: A + 'a,
{
    iterator
        .into_iter()
        .map(|a| Box::new(a))
        .collect::<Vec<Box<A + 'a>>>()
}
```

However, this fails to compile, saying:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<std::boxed::Box<A + 'a>>: std::iter::FromIterator<std::boxed::Box<<I as std::iter::IntoIterator>::Item>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:11:10
   |
11 |         .collect::<Vec<Box<A + 'a>>>()
   |          ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<std::boxed::Box<A + 'a>>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `std::boxed::Box<<I as std::iter::IntoIterator>::Item>`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<std::boxed::Box<<I as std::iter::IntoIterator>::Item>>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<std::boxed::Box<A + 'a>>`
   = help: consider adding a `where std::vec::Vec<std::boxed::Box<A + 'a>>: std::iter::FromIterator<std::boxed::Box<<I as std::iter::IntoIterator>::Item>>` bound
```

This error kind of makes sense, but then I don't see why there's no problem with the following:

```
fn test<'a, T: A + 'a>(t: T) -> Box<A + 'a> {
    Box::new(t)
}
```

How is that any different? How can I express that I'd like to `Box` them as `A`s, rather than whatever type they may be?

Comment: And what happened when you followed the two "help" lines in the error message?

Comment: @Shepmaster that would restrict the types that can be used in the function, would it not? Unless the necessary impl somehow just happens to exist...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast the `Box<I::Item>` into a `Box<A>`:

```
fn test2<'a, I>(iterator: I) -> Vec<Box<dyn A + 'a>>
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: A + 'a,
{
    iterator
        .into_iter()
        .map(|a| Box::new(a) as Box<dyn A>)
        .collect()
}
```

> How is [returning `Box::new` directly] any different?

As [Sven Marnach points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180008/how-can-i-box-the-contents-of-an-iterator-of-a-type-that-implements-a-trait/48180117?noredirect=1#comment83349059_48180117):

> The reason why you don't need an explicit cast in the function is that the last statement of a block is a *coercion site* and coercions happen implicitly at these sites. See [the chapter on coercions in the nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html) for further details.

Comment: Interesting, I was not aware this was possible. Nothing in the documentation for `as` indicates it can be used this way...

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/casting-between-types.html

Comment: @AlphaModder indeed. The best book link I can find is [in the second edition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-02-advanced-lifetimes.html).

Comment: @AlphaModder The reason why you don't need an explicit cast in the function is that the last statement of a block is a _coercion site_ and coercions happen implicitly at these sites.  See the [chapter on coercions in the nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html) for further details.

Comment: You may be able to get away with just telling the compiler it needs to perform the coercion using `as _`